# Fetch data from JavaScript getting from AJAX (JSON) response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "firstName":"vishal",
   "lastName":"gehlot",
   "title":"Mr.",
   "officePhone":"643636",
   "lastModified":""
},
{
   "id":"2",
   "firstName":"daya",
   "lastName":"dayaji",
   "title":"Mr.",
   "officePhone":"858587",
   "lastModified":""
},
{
   "id":"7",
   "firstName":"tripti",
   "lastName":"tri",
   "title":"ms",
   "officePhone":"4535",
   "lastModified":""
},
{
   "id":"59",
   "firstName":"Daya",
   "lastName":"s",
   "title":"",
   "officePhone":"698789",
   "lastModified":""
},
{
   "id":"89",
   "firstName":"prashant",
   "lastName":"p",
   "title":"",
   "officePhone":"987698",
   "lastModified":""
}
```

How to fetch each data using JavaScript?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    alert('inside');
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
 // alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
   // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var obj = [{"id":"1","firstName":"vishal","lastName":"gehlot","title":"Mr.","officePhone":"643636","lastModified":""},{"id":"2","firstName":"daya","lastName":"dayaji","title":"Mr.","officePhone":"858587","lastModified":""},{"id":"7","firstName":"tripti","lastName":"tri","title":"ms","officePhone":"4535","lastModified":""},{"id":"59","firstName":"Daya","lastName":"s","title":"","officePhone":"698789","lastModified":""},{"id":"89","firstName":"prashant","lastName":"p","title":"","officePhone":"987698","lastModified":""}];
      alert(obj);
      for(var index=0; index<obj.length;index++)   {

          alert((obj[index].id));
          alert((obj[index].firstName));
              //like this....
          }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","localapi.php?mode=list",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
<input type="button" value="Check Data" onclick="loadXMLDoc()" />
```

this code is working fro me but when same response which i have taken in obj getting from ajax it is not working ...what will be the issue

Comment: You have an array of json objects, but the array brakes, `[...]`, are missing (at least in what you have posted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code:-

```
var obj=[{"id":"1","firstName":"vishal","lastName":"gehlot","title":"Mr.","officePhone":"643636","lastModified":""},{"id":"2","firstName":"daya","lastName":"dayaji","title":"Mr.","officePhone":"858587","lastModified":""},{"id":"7","firstName":"tripti","lastName":"tri","title":"ms","officePhone":"4535","lastModified":""},{"id":"59","firstName":"Daya","lastName":"s","title":"","officePhone":"698789","lastModified":""},{"id":"89","firstName":"prashant","lastName":"p","title":"","officePhone":"987698","lastModified":""}];


        for(var index=0; index<obj.length;index++)   {

            document.write(obj[index].id)
            document.write(obj[index].firstName)
                //like this....
            }
```

link:-
http://jsfiddle.net/rcDue/3/

Comment: Normal `for` loop is used for arrays not objects :)

Comment: @Blaster If you examine the data, you'd see it *is* an array, with each element being a json object, so sandeep's code would work, but yours would not.

Comment: @sandeeppatel Check my code ..when i m putting data manually it is working but not working with ajax response

Comment: @sandeeppatel Thanks it worked for me....the mistake i did was ..after ajax response i need to do eval with ajax resonse          var obj = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');

Answer (score 1):

> How to fetch **each** data using javascript

Like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJSONData);

for (var x in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    console.log(obj[x]);
  }
}
```

The above code uses [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert your JSON string to JavaScript object and then uses `for-in` loop to read each property of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a javascript object. lets say you saved it in a variable

`var myObjects = {...}`

Access it with the simple "dot" notation

`alert(myObject.id)` produces an alert "1"
`alert(myObject.firstName)` produces "vishal"

Edit: sorry, to get each property:

try

```
for (var propertyName in myObject) {
     alert(myObject[propertyName]);
}
```

Comment: `How to fetch each data using javascript`